# Default Form Field Value Clears unless Unique

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Is there a better way to do this?

I have a form field. Using jQuery (because I do not have access to the HTML), I need to set the default value to 'Year/Make/Model' and when the field get focus, if that's the text in there, it goes away. But if it's custom text, then the field stays in tact.

#### This is the code I wrote...

```
var textVal = 'Year/Make/Model';

  $('form li:contains("Vehicle Details") input').attr('value', textVal).on('focus', function(){
    if ($(this).attr('value') == textVal)
      $(this).attr('value','');
  }).on('blur', function(){
    if ($(this).attr('value') == '')
      $(this).attr('value',textVal);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WVyf8/2

This works, but I am fairly certain there's a better way. I'm a novice at JS. Please be kind :)

Thank you!

Comment: If this works, what's your concern?

Comment: Fiddle added for fiddling.

Comment: anthonygore, my concern is getting better as a coder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if HTML 5 is no problem, I would use the built-in placeholder feature. here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CT5nV/3/

```
$('form li:contains("Vehicle Details") input').attr('placeholder', "year/make/model");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a better performance by not accessing the DOM multiple times

```
var textVal = 'Year/Make/Model';

  $('form li:contains("Vehicle Details") input').attr('value', textVal).on('focus', function(){
    var element = $(this); 
    if (element.attr('value') == textVal)
      element.attr('value','');
  }).on('blur', function(){
     var element = $(this); 
    if (element.attr('value') == '')
     element.attr('value',textVal);
  });
```

**Edit**

You can simply add `placeholder` attribute

`$('form li:contains("Vehicle Details") input').attr('placeholder', textVal);`

But please note that this is not supported in some versions of IE